# Why i cant create index in laravel?

Tags: laravel, indexing, controller

i want to create index but its showing 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Project' not found

```
public function index()
{
    $projects=Project::all()->toArray();
   return view('projects.index',compact('projects'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add `use App\Project;` top of controller if Project model file in in app folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Or other way is using `\App\Project::all()`